# What are 'var_8', 'var_C' actually mean?

Tags: disassembly, x86

I am sorry if this is really a silly question. I am trying to learn reverse engineering. What I can't understand is those 'var_8', 'var_12'. Are they just variables? What are the use of them in the following code? If someone give me an overview of what this piece of code actually does then it will boost up my learning process. I know the first four instructions which are really just setting up the stack frame for the function and I know all the registers used in here. I need to know what this function actually doing so that I can judge if I am figuring it out right or wrong.

```
00611e63 8BFF                            mov        edi, edi                ; XREF=0x611721
00611e65 55                              push       ebp
00611e66 8BEC                            mov        ebp, esp
00611e68 83EC10                          sub        esp, 0x10
00611e6b A174897000                      mov        eax, dword [ds:0x708974]
00611e70 8365F800                        and        dword [ss:ebp-0x10+var_8], 0x0
00611e74 8365FC00                        and        dword [ss:ebp-0x10+var_12], 0x0
00611e78 53                              push       ebx
00611e79 57                              push       edi
00611e7a BF4EE640BB                      mov        edi, 0xbb40e64e
00611e7f BB0000FFFF                      mov        ebx, 0xffff0000
00611e84 3BC7                            cmp        eax, edi
00611e86 740D                            je         0x611e95
```

Answer (score 1):

The given answer is already great but I think it could be nice to clarify something.

You are saying:

> I know the first four instructions which are really just setting up the stack frame for the function

In fact the first instruction (`mov edi, edi`) is not part of the stack frame mecanism. It is a hot-patch point often used in Windows DLL. [This page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583) could give you insight about how it works.

Comment: please use comments or edits for clarifications, don't post "answers" that don't answer the question asked.

Comment: OK sorry. It seemed right to me because I do not have enought reputation to do a comment and an edit did not seem right to me.

Answer (score 0):

These `var_*` are numeric offsets of something which Ida detected as variables on the stack.

In one of the lines with these constants you can see the following:

```
dword [ss:ebp-0x10+var_8]
```

This actually references a dword (4 bytes) from address which is computed in the following way:

from a stack segment (`ss`) a value of register `ebp` - `0x10` + `var_8` constant (which is defined at the start of the function (you'll see there something like `var_8 = dword ptr -8h` ).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you tell me why are we doing those two and operations? What is this function doing, is it comparing the length of two strings? Is it comparing two int values?

Comment: "and" instruction is used for zeroing local variables var_8 and var_12 by "binary and" operation. The code snippet you provided is not a full function,   and the comparison operation compares dword at address ds:0x708974 with value 0xbb40e64e .

Answer (score 0):

They are the local variables in a function. The rules of them are:

1. Ordered on the stack frame.
2. Pointer by ESP register.

Eg. var_4 = SS:[ESP - 4], var_8 = [ESP - 8], var_C = SS:[ESP - C], ...

Comment: No, they are just variables with a negative value, and definitely *not* constraned to the ESP register. For an example of that, just look at OP's dump: `ebp-0x10+var_8`.